# Applying jquery to show progress bar on a particular <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a progress bar for a pdf-reading module. I want to show the progress as the reader scrolls down the container having PDF files. Now I have applied jquery ofcourse for this but there is some issues emerging and not obtaining the desired result. Issue here is the progress bar does show progress but it works on the whole window scroll only. What I want is to have show the progress on bar when the pdf container is scrolled down in that window. I have made codes for that but somehow its unresponsive for pdf-container. Any suggestions and help will be highly appreciated.

Here is my `<div>` that is showing the PDF,

```
 <div id="viewer" class="pdf-viewer" oncontextmenu="return false" data-url="../sadmin/studyMaterial/<?php echo $db->idToField("tbl_studymaterials", "file_ppt", $chapterId) ; ?>"></div>
 <span><progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress></span>
```

And the jquery that I am using is,

```
$(".pdf-viewer").scroll(function () {  
  var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
        d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(window).height();
        scrollPercent = (s / (d-c)) * 100;
        var position = scrollPercent;

   $("#progressbar").attr('value', position);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the incorrect DOM node for the `scrollTop()` values in your script. Since you want to track the scroll position of the PDF container, you should simply reference it's own `scrollTop()` value, i.e. `$(this).scrollTop()`.

Also, instead of checking the document height, you should check the [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) of the element to get its full content height. The property is native to a DOM node, so you can simply use `this.scrollHeight`.

Here's the updated code:

```
$(".pdf-viewer").scroll(function () {  
  var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
      d = this.scrollHeight,
      c = $(this).height(),
      position = (s / (d-c)) * 100;

   $("#progressbar").attr('value', position);
});
```

---

And actually, you don't even really need to use jQuery methods to retrieve the dimensions:

1. Use [`Element.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) instead of [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to retrieve the scroll position
2. Use [`Element.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) instead of [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) to retrieve the element's defined height (sans bottom scrollbar, if any)

And you get this:

```
$(".pdf-viewer").scroll(function() {
    var s = this.scrollTop,
        d = this.scrollHeight,
        c = this.clientHeight,
        position = (s / (d - c)) * 100;

    $("#progressbar").attr('value', position);

});
```

---

### jQuery-based solution

A proof-of-concept example with a dummy DOM:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".pdf-viewer").scroll(function() {
    var s = this.scrollTop,
      d = this.scrollHeight,
      c = this.clientHeight,
      position = (s / (d - c)) * 100;

    $("#progressbar").attr('value', position);

  });
});
```

```css
#viewer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viewer" class="pdf-viewer">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>

  <p>Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra
    nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.</p>

  <p>Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero
    venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna.</p>
</div>
<span><progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress></span>
```

---

### Native JS solution

If you do not want to use jQuery, that is also entirely possible:

```js
var viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');
viewer.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var s = this.scrollTop,
      d = this.scrollHeight,
      c = this.clientHeight,
      position = (s / (d - c)) * 100;

  document.getElementById('progressbar').value = position;
});
```

```css
#viewer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="viewer" class="pdf-viewer">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>

  <p>Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra
    nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.</p>

  <p>Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero
    venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna.</p>
</div>
<span><progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress></span>
```

Comment: thanks for the time mate. But unfortunately the bar doesn't shows any activity as expected by your code snippet. Adding <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> makes the PDF's disappear from the container. And without it PDF's are visible but the progress bar shows no activity on scroll. Something can be updated??

Comment: @Ansh Don't include that `<script>` tag, it is only used to load jQuery in the code snippet. Do you have jQuery already loaded on your page?

Comment: No not yet. But once I am using the <script> , the whole pdf's goes away and shows blank container. What more can be done? I am  very thankful to you

Comment: @Ansh I have added a native JS solution to your question. Adding jQuery to your page should not break stuff, so I am suspecting some conflict between jQuery and whatever library you are using for your PDF viewer. Also, **always check your console log**: I cannot tell you what went wrong without any details.

Comment: ok. I will look thoroughly and get back to you on this. But still thanks for your time.

Comment: Can I have some insights on how to use FireBug for this??